# Waring problem generalizations and theta-function

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, integer-partitions, theta-functions

My question is twofold:

1. Can the Waring problem be expressed with the Jacobi theta function
   or some analog (as is the case for $k=2$) for general $k$? Say for $k=4$
   or $k=6$, are these able to be understood with some properties of the
   theta function?

   w. Can the Hardy-Littlewood circle method (used for $k=4$) be used for
   asymptotic bounds of general $k$, or at least small $k$ (say $k=6$)?

Comment: No, $f(q)=\sum_n q^{n^4}$ is not a theta function. Yes the circle method should give useful estimates because from that the Mellin transform of $\sum_n e^{-n^4 x}$ is $\Gamma(s)\zeta(4s)$ you know a very good asymptotic expansion of $f(q)$

Comment: @reuns sorry, is the sum you mention the expression for k=4 or have I misunderstood your statement? What would the expression be for k=6? I don’t see, atleast obviously, why there shouldn’t be some expression for general k of the waring problem that atleast resembles a theta function?